# Datetime adding hours

Tags: mysql, database

output

2017-02-16 10:25:00

how to add one hour to the time

Comment: check this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_date_format

Answer (score 2):

Format the date before inserting the in sql like below.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('19 January 2017 - 09:30 am', '%d %M  %Y - %h:%i %p'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Use just the `DATE_FORMAT` part in your insert statement.